# Cmake: add_subproject & add_subfolder

Tags: makefile, cmake

I currently want to add some self written classes ("mycode.cpp" and "mycode.hpp") to a big existing C++ project that is configured with Cmake. These classes are located in "myfolder" which is located in the "lib/pointrender" folder of the existing project (see dummy hierarchy below).

```
|- libs 
|    |- core
|    |   |- ...
|    |- pointrender
|        |- myfolder
|        |     |- mycode.cpp
|        |     |- mycode.hpp
|        |- existingclasses.cpp
|        |- existingclasses.hpp
|        |- project.cmake
|- CMakeLists.txt
```

In the CMakesLists.txt the pointrender folder is declared as a subproject.

```
declare_subproject(libs/pointrender)
```

How do I best add my code to the existing cmake configuration? Do I add it as a subfolder in the project.cmake with a seperate CMakeLists.txt in myfolder? Or do I best add it as a subproject with a seperate project.cmake file? What's the difference?

Comment: By the looks of it `project.cmake` is used instead of a `CMakeLists.txt` file when the folder is declared as a subproject. It has the same syntax as the `CMakeLists.txt` files, but they don't start with a `project()` command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This `project.cmake` is being `include()`d be some `CMakeLists.txt` and get's executed as part of it. Authors of project you are using rolled this out for some reason, so it's probably better to use their infrastructure to add custom code.

The usual way to do this is writing your own `CMakeLists.txt` and `add_subdirectory()`ing it from the upper level.

If you wish more details you should update your question with `project.cmake` contents.